# issue with order syntax on opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

We are getting the below error while fetching the orders on opencart.

error:

```
{"status":200,"data":"\"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDBserver version for the right syntax to use near 'order ORDER BY order_id DESC' at line 1<br \\\/>Error No: 1064<br \\\/>SELECT * FROM order ORDER BY order_id DESC\""}
```

please help

I am using opencart 3.0.3.8

I am new to opencart, still learning it so I didn't find a solution for the same. I need help here.

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324634/error-when-try-to-update-table-name-order

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL contains the word "order" for the order table. However, order is a keyword. You need to put it in backticks - ie `order`

Answer (score 0):

It's conflicting with the predefined word ORDER BY
So you need to change it to be `order`